# PyQT Accessing UI elements from other classes(Qthread) in same file

Tags: inheritance, pyqt, pyqt5, qthread, qdialog

I have seen similar questions ,but no luck from my case. I am trying to access the UI elements from other class,but 
 i am getting the following error. error in **"worker_temp"** function

```
AttributeError: 'rack_temp' object has no attribute 'ui'
```

**code which i tried:** - **main.py**

```
from PyQt5.uic.properties import QtWidgets
from master.ui_code.fast_charging_ui import Ui_Dialog
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow, QApplication, QDialog, QLabel, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer, QObject, pyqtSignal, QRunnable, pyqtSlot, QThreadPool, QByteArray, QEventLoop, QThread

import sys

class MainWindow(QDialog):

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.ui = Ui_Dialog()    
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.unit_1.setCurrentIndex(0)
        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        self.test = rack_temp()
        self.test.start()


    def door_1_check(self):
        print "door check"

class rack_temp(QThread):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        QThread.__init__(self, parent)
        super(rack_temp, self).__init__(parent)
        self.threadpool = QThreadPool()
        self.dataCollectionTimer = QTimer()
        self.dataCollectionTimer.moveToThread(self)
        self.dataCollectionTimer.timeout.connect(self.worker_temp)
        self.worker_temp()

    def worker_temp(self):
        print "test "
        self.ui.unit_1.setCurrentIndex(2)

    def run(self):
        self.dataCollectionTimer.start(2000)
        loop = QEventLoop()
        loop.exec_()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MainWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Can anyone tell me why i am not able to inherit the elements from other class?
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Try declare `rack_temp` as global

Comment: @Carlos : Its not a global variable issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a solution for this and its working.We cannot directly call UI elements from different thread.We should use signals and slot mechanism or the other method is QMetaObject.I tried with signals and slot method.[Examples](https://www.pythoncentral.io/pysidepyqt-tutorial-creating-your-own-signals-and-slots/)

```
class Rack_Temperature(QtCore.QThread):
    slot1 = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list)
    slot2 = QtCore.pyqtSignal(list) 

    def run(self):

        while True:
            try:
                QtCore.QThread.msleep(3000)

                self.slot1.emit("yourdata")
            except Exception as err:
                print err
class MainWindow(QDialog):

    def __init__(self,*args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.myclass_temp = Rack_Temperature()
        self.myclass_temp.start()
        elf.myclass_temp.slot1.connect(self.test_method)
```